# How to write this SQL query with Laravel elequoent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I tried this in laravel, but it's not working. I can't get it to work it's working when I use it straight on PHPMyAdmin

```
SELECT service,
count(*) as total_count,
sum(if(status ='Successful',1,0)) as successful_count,
sum(if(status ='Failed',1,0)) as failed_count
FROM `wallet_ledgers`
WHERE operator = "-"
AND user_id = 5
group by service
```

this is the desired output [The way the table should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOAxH.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DB::raw`

Link: [Laravel-raw-expressions](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#raw-expressions)

```
$result = DB::table('wallet_ledgers')
                     ->select(DB::raw("service, count(*) as total_count, sum(if(status ='Successful',1,0)) as successful_count, sum(if(status ='Failed',1,0)) as failed_count"))
                     ->where([
                             [ 'operator', '=', '-'],
                             ['user_id', '=', '5'],
                             ])
                     ->groupBy('service')
                     ->get();
```